What happens when a coroutine returns to a suspended coroutine?
Suppose I have two coroutines, coroutine_a and coroutine_b. In coroutine_a it calls:
co_await awaiter_a;

The awaiter_a::await_suspend returns a coroutine handler of coroutine_b. As a result, coroutine_b is resumed. Then, in coroutine_b, it calls:
co_await awaiter_b;

The awaiter_b::await_suspend returns void. As a result, control should be returned to its caller/resumer coroutine_a. What will happen when control is returned to coroutine_a?
I think there are two options:

coroutine_a returns to its caller.
coroutine_a stays suspended until someone resumes it.

Which one is correct? Or is it something else?

Symmetric transfer means that when coroutine_a's  await_suspend returns coroutine_b, coroutine_a leaves the picture and it's caller becomes the caller of coroutine_b.

@RaymondChen That sounds like it could be an answer.

@RaymondChen Thanks for answering. That's exactly what I want.

This is explained by [expr.await]/5:

The await-expression evaluates the (possibly-converted) o expression and the await-ready expression, then:

If the result of await-ready is false, the coroutine is considered suspended. Then:

If the type of await-suspend is std​::​coroutine_handle<Z>, await-suspend.resume() is evaluated.
[Note 1: This resumes the coroutine referred to by the result of await-suspend. Any number of coroutines can be successively resumed in this fashion, eventually returning control flow to the current coroutine caller or resumer ([dcl.fct.def.coroutine]). — end note]
Otherwise, if the type of await-suspend is bool, await-suspend is evaluated, and the coroutine is resumed if the result is false.
Otherwise, await-suspend is evaluated.

If the evaluation of await-suspend exits via an exception, the exception is caught, the coroutine is resumed, and the exception is immediately rethrown ([except.throw]). Otherwise, control flow returns to the current coroutine caller or resumer ([dcl.fct.def.coroutine]) without exiting any scopes ([stmt.jump]). The point in the coroutine immediately prior to control returning to its caller or resumer is a coroutine suspend point.

If the result of await-ready is true, or when the coroutine is resumed other than by rethrowing an exception from await-suspend, the await-resume expression is evaluated, and its result is the result of the await-expression.



So, co_await awaiter_a first suspends coroutine A, then goes to the first subbullet and calls .resume() on the handle for coroutine B. When coroutine B is suspended and returns control to coroutine A, then we've just finished the second subbullet in  coroutine A, which means we go to the paragraph at the end of the first bullet, and control flow returns to the caller or resumer of coroutine A.
(Note 1 also explains this. Returning a coroutine handle from await-suspend basically just inserts a coroutine at the front of the queue to be resumed before the coroutine that would otherwise be resumed if await-suspend were of type void.)


co_await awaiter_a;

To write this code into a function means that the function is waiting on a value that will be generated by awaiter_a. Therefore, this current function is not allowed to proceed until awaiter_a has generated that value.
If await_suspend returns a coroutine handle, this means that execution continues into that coroutine handle. However, this doesn't change the meaning of suspension; the current coroutine will stop until awaiter_a is ready to produce a value.
This effectively means that the new handle (from your coroutine_b) replaces the current handle (from your coroutine_a which just suspended itself).
If await_suspend returns nothing, then that just suspends the coroutine. So when coroutine_b does a co_await, it is suspended. But that's it. Control flow continues on from the caller of coroutine_a as if coroutine_a was suspended... because it was and still is suspended.
